# How do I properly implement a caching struct in Rust for lazily-computed values?

Tags: rust

In Rust, I'm searching for a more concise and idiomatic way to define a cache for expensive calculations.

In Chapter 13 from the Second Edition of *The Rust Programming Language*, the authors leave an exercise for the reader to refactor a struct to return lazily-computed values.

After four days of trial and error, I came up with:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[allow(dead_code)]
struct Cache<T> 
    where T: Fn(u32) -> u32
{
    calculation: T,
    internal: HashMap<u32, u32>
}

#[allow(dead_code)]
impl<T> Cache<T>
    where T: Fn(u32) -> u32
{
    fn new(calculation: T) -> Cache<T> {
        Cache {
            calculation,
            internal: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    fn set(&mut self, arg: u32, value: u32) -> u32 {
        self.internal.insert(arg, value);
        self.get(arg)
    }

    fn get(&mut self, arg: u32) -> u32 {
        self.internal[&arg]
    }

    fn value(&mut self, arg: u32) -> u32 {
        match self.internal.contains_key(&arg) {
            true => {
                self.get(arg)
            },
            false => {
                self.set(arg, (self.calculation)(arg))
            },
        }
    }
}
```

For the test function:

```rust
#[test]
fn call_with_different_values() {
    let mut c = Cache::new(|a| a);
    let _v1 = c.value(1);
    let v2 = c.value(2);
    assert_eq!(v2, 2);
}
```

Can I improve this `impl`? Is there a more acceptable way for this to be written?

Comment: Perhaps you want codereview.SE instead of stackoverflow? This question looks a bit too broad.

Comment: Thank you @SOFe, I'll keep that in mind for next time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- In `set()`, `self.get(arg)` can be simplified to `value`.
- `get()` only needs a non-mutable `&self`.
- `get()` and `set()` don’t really seem that helpful in the first place.
- The [`hash_map::Entry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html) API can help you simplify `value()`.

  ```
  fn value(&mut self, arg: u32) -> u32 {
      let Self { internal, calculation } = self;
      let entry = internal.entry(arg);
      *entry.or_insert_with(|| (calculation)(arg))
  }
  ```

Then the minor style things:

- You can use `Self` instead of repeating the struct name inside the `impl`.
- Trailing commas are good.

In all:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub struct Cache<T>
    where T: Fn(u32) -> u32
{
    calculation: T,
    internal: HashMap<u32, u32>,
}

impl<T> Cache<T>
    where T: Fn(u32) -> u32
{
    pub fn new(calculation: T) -> Cache<T> {
        Self {
            calculation,
            internal: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn value(&mut self, arg: u32) -> u32 {
        let Self { internal, calculation } = self;
        let entry = internal.entry(arg);
        *entry.or_insert_with(|| (calculation)(arg))
    }
}

#[test]
fn call_with_different_values() {
    let mut c = Cache::new(|a| a);
    let _v1 = c.value(1);
    let v2 = c.value(2);
    assert_eq!(v2, 2);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=40f1ae68dc2b09e0011f2bef7dc864c1)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time out to completely type this out. I especially like your demonstration of using the dereference to entry in `Cache::value`.

Comment: Hello again! I was wondering if the closure return for `(calculation)(arg)` can be extended to any `impl Fn` for `calculation`, or if it needs an extra heap allocation to tie down tuple's 0th entry?

Comment: @DavidGolembiowski: I’m not sure what you mean by that. Playground link?